# How to access environment variables in Javascript for Automation on OS X?

Tags: automation, javascript

I am using JavaScript for Automation in an Alfred workflow. I want to access the various environment variables that Alfred sets up. How do I access the environment variable like alfred_version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have Alfred installed however I would think the following method should work.

For example, using the Script Editor set to JavaScript the following code returned my login name.

```
ObjC.import('stdlib')
$.getenv('LOGNAME')
```

So, I'd assume that if "`alfred_version`" is the actual environment variable, then the following might work as well.

```
ObjC.import('stdlib')
$.getenv('alfred_version')
```

Comment: Sorry. I have used these to get knowledge, but I think this is only my second question on one, and the only one that had an answer. I think I checked it now. But, I do not have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: How do you set environment variables (in my case, for testing purposes)?